# How to retrieve data based on conditions in firebase like sql we are using where conditons

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[please check below table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nywbn.png)

> Please help for how to retrieve data based on address, salary, company.

Answer (score 0):

You can use orderbychild function that sort data based on key.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#data-order

In addition you can speed up query time by using indexing https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data

Comment: could you please explain the sample code for query.

Comment: For example If I have database structure like this example https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#fanout You can retrieve data based on name key and If you write class like  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once You can use retrieved data java object.